# Add "Get [app name]" beneath Facebook wall-post with a link to a site

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have made an Android app that writes your current location to your wall.

When I look at other Facebook-apps I can see a small link just beneath the post that says "Get [app name]".

I mean something like this:

[image]

How can I add such a link to my posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Actions" parameter. See the post documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

> **actions**
>   A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action). read_stream. A list of JSON objects containing the 'name' and 'link'.

`actions={"name": "View on Zombo", "link": "http://www.zombo.com"}`